# Cron job to check all folders of mailbox for every users stored in mysql database

Tags: java, cron, imap, jakarta-mail, cron-task

I am using `javamail` to read the mailbox. Now i need to poll to the mailbox and check for any new mails received, sent, drafts saved etc. What is the good way to do that something like how `push mail` does? For now i am taking `imap` and `gmail` but would have to extend support for `pop3` and other common email accounts. So i was wondering what to use and how to do it such that it suits in most cases. Is there any schedular job support in `javamail` that triggers immediately for any activity  in mailbox and read it or any ready made script available that looks for all the folders of mailbox for every users in the database and immediately triggers the java code to read mails of the user for any new email in regular interval time

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling a job is completely orthogonal to JavaMail.  You can find many solutions for job scheduling in Java; pick one you like and then write a job that uses JavaMail.

Checking for "new" activity of the sort you described is non-trivial.  You're going to need to keep track of the state of the mailboxes for each user so you can see what's changed the next time you look at the mailbox.

And of course doing this for multiple users means you'll need to have the authentication credentials (e.g., passwords) for all these users.

Doing this all with pop3 is essentially impossible since you only have access to a user's Inbox.